# How to find the minimum of $f(x)=(\sin(x)+\cos(x)+\tan(x)+\cot(x)+\sec(x)+\csc(x))^2$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, optimization

I need to find the minimum of $f(x)$ with 
$$f(x)=(\sin(x)+\cos(x)+\tan(x)+\cot(x)+\sec(x)+\csc(x))^2$$
Could you help me with some clues?

Comment: Do you know what a derivative is?

Comment: @ja72 yes, I know.

Comment: I found the answer numerically, but I am not sure how to proceed analytically.

Comment: Calculating the derivative will not work.

Comment: @LordSoth it's true. Calculating the derivative the difficulty remains unchanged.

Comment: @Queaviouer : Plot the function using some software so you can see what quadrant the minimizing angle is in.  Take the derivative of the function _with the outside square removed_, set it equal to $0$, and solve for $x$. Do you have reason to believe that there will be a nice, closed-form solution?

Comment: Is face of [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%5Csin%28x%29%2B%5Ccos%28x%29%2B%5Ctan%28x%29%2B%5Ccot%28x%29%2B%5Csec%28x%29%2B%5Ccsc%28x%29%29%5E2+minimum) I think it's fair to ask: how did you come across this problem?

Comment: @GitGud it's homework

Answer (score 12):

You can do the following:

Let $$\sin x + \cos x = y$$

Then we have that $$\tan x + \cot x = \frac{2}{y^2 -1}$$

and

$$\sec x  + \csc x = \frac{2y}{y^2-1}$$

I believe $$\sin x + \cos x + \tan x + \cot x + \sec x  + \csc x  $$ simplifies to $$y + \frac{2}{y-1}$$ (but I tried doing it in my head, so might have made mistakes).

And you can use the standard calculus techniques, now. (but take care to eliminate the corner cases etc).

Comment: I can do it from here. Thank you.

Comment: (+1) This is classic.:) My answer hint no where..

Answer (score 0):

To built upon @Queayiouer if you split the function as

$$ f(x) = \left( g(x) \right)^2 =  \left( \left(\sin x+\frac{1}{\sin x}\right) + \left(\cos x+\frac{1}{\cos x}\right) + \left(\tan x+\frac{1}{\tan x}\right) \right)^2 $$

where the minimum occurs if $g(x)=0$ or $g'(x)=0$. The first is not going to happen.

So now we have

$$ g(x) = g_1(x) + g_2(x) + g_3(x) = \left(\sin x+\frac{1}{\sin x}\right) + \left(\cos x+\frac{1}{\cos x}\right) + \left(\tan x+\frac{1}{\tan x}\right)  $$

Let find if they three functions have a common minimum since

$$ g_1'(x) = \cos(x) \left(1-\frac{1}{\sin^2 x} \right) = 0 $$
  $$ g_2'(x) = \sin(x) \left(\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}-1 \right) = 0 $$
  $$ g_3'(x) = \tan^2 x - \frac{1}{\tan^2 x} = 0$$

Unfortunately those are never all zero at the same time. So my guess it to proceed numerically with Newton-Raphson method where

$$ x \rightarrow x - \frac{ g_1(x) + g_2(x) + g_3(x) }{ g_1'(x) + g_2'(x) + g_3'(x) } $$

starting from $x=1$ or something. I get between $2.5<x<2.7$.